# Unable to install "org.Hs.eg.db" in Rstudio

Tags: r, package

I tried to install the package `org.Hs.eg.db` from the bio-conductor, but the Rstudio failed to install.

The returning warning message is as followed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLzd.png)

And my `SessionInfo()` is as followed:

[image]

My .LibPaths() is as followed: `D:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library`

The output of the installed.packages is as followed:

Could anynone help to debug this, it has plagued me for half a month, I tried all sorts of means, still no good result. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show `installed.packages()` output. Kindly show the information above the warning messages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, the output of the installed.packages is too long, how can I add it in the comment?

Comment: Show information above warning messages. check if `curl` and `Rcurl` are installed. The package works for me.

Comment: The Chinese in the information above warning means 'D :\Program' is neither internal or external command, not executable programe or batch file. Does that suggest I should change the PATH? But it works for other packages though.

Comment: Unexpected error !!. Are you pasting `source("https://bioconductor.orgbiocLite.R")
biocLite("org.Hs.eg.db")`   in your R console and then enter.

Comment: Yes,I did! It's quite confusing that I don't know where the bug is.